# How validation done for input box1 or input box2 & input box3

Tags: angular7

I have a form where i need to validate if input box 1 is null means they can provide input box 2 & input box 3 value and can submit form and opposite can also be done.

How can i achieve this? i am new to Angular

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean that only one of the Inputs can be empty in order to submit the form?

Comment: yes,in validation i am facing issue @Ashok

Answer (score 0):

This is just a straight forward question about the form validation. Just go through the link at stack overflow to how can you ask a question for a specific topic. You need to first go through the Angular documentation about the Form Validation and if you stuck to create the form validation following that you can come to this place with your samples to ask the question. Please follow this in your future question and since this is your first question keep it in your mind for the future. Best of luck.

By the way, just go through the following links to understand the Angular - Form Validation.

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation
https://angular-templates.io/tutorials/about/angular-forms-and-validations

Comment: if it was straightforward i would have not asked  i stuck here because of or condition

Comment: Then post here what you have tried so far and in which point you are struggling.